# Unable to connect to Jedis in AndroidStudio (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, redis, jedis

My apllication is crushing when I press the button which is responsible for connecting to Redis database using Jedis client and changing TextView to value which stores jedis.ping() (It should return "Pong"). 
Code and Log are below. Same operations (connection to Redis and printing jedis.ping()) works perfectly in Eclipse. Maybe I insert code connected with Jedis in wrong place? I know too litle about Android programming. Thanks in advance!

```
package com.samfoundation.samfoundation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button click;
    TextView show;
    @Override


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        show = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);




        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
                String value = jedis.ping();
                show.setText(value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Log:

```
2020-04-09 19:53:22.473 32666-32666/com.samfoundation.samfoundation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.samfoundation.samfoundation, PID: 32666
    redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed connecting to host localhost:6379
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:204)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:100)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:125)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:120)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.ping(BinaryClient.java:113)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.ping(BinaryJedis.java:188)
        at com.samfoundation.samfoundation.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7259)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7236)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27892)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
        at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:552)
        at java.net.Socket.setReuseAddress(Socket.java:1493)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:171)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:100) 
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:125) 
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:120) 
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.ping(BinaryClient.java:113) 
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.ping(BinaryJedis.java:188) 
        at com.samfoundation.samfoundation.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7259) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7236) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27892) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.samfoundation.samfoundation">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please share the Manifest.xml

Comment: @BömachtBlau done, edited the question. Should I have changed something in this file?

Comment: You need to add [<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element). This may not be sufficient but it's definitely necessary

Comment: @BömachtBlau I'm still struggling with a problem. I added this line to AndroidManifest, but after I had a NetworkOnMainThreadException. I searched for some solutions and tried to set up Jedis connection in AsyncTask (not quite sure that I did it correctly). Now I have a "stack" of errors "Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) ".

Comment: Well, you're making progress :) This sounds like the server does not want to talk to your app. Since I'm not a network expert, I'd suggest googling first (I found [a post](https://community.ipswitch.com/s/article/Connection-Error-ECONNREFUSED-Connection-refused-by-the-server) indicating that there may be a firewall configuration problem) and then maybe asking a new question. Just one thought which may be helpful: for the android app, "localhost" is the android device. If you want to connect e.g. to a server on your development machine, you need to use its ip address in the local network